# Ubuntu themes directory

Tags: unity, themes, directory, tweak

I downloaded a few themes from various ppa's, and i don't like the button for closing, minimalizing etc. Are those themes stored in some kind of directory where i can edit their files? I'm using Unity Tweak Tool for applying them. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default themes directory is `/usr/share/themes/` but it's editable only for root. If You want to edit themes the default directory for current user would be `~/.themes/` I believe.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't able to find it for the first time, then i pasted the path into nautilus and I am there! Thank you so much, this helped a lot! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. ;)  That's truly not easy to get to '/user/share/themes' in Nautilus due to fact that there is no "up" or "back" button while You are in home folder by default. You need to choose "Computer" or however it's called in devices section to get to '/'. On the other hand '.themes' as it starts with '.' is a hidden folder. You can show all hidden files with ctrl + h hotkey or in Nautilus settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
locate themes|grep Ambiance| grep png|more
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-button-active-disabled.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-button-active-hover.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-button-active.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-button-disabled.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-button-hover.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-button-toolbar-active.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-button-toolbar.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-button.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-check-mixed-alt.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-check-mixed-disabled-alt.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-check-mixed-disabled.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-check-mixed-hover-alt.png
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/backdrop-check-mixed-hover.png
 ...
```

---

You can find the others in the same directory `/usr/share/themes/` with their respective names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the location of some app, file or anything else in the terminal type:

***whereis*** 'name_you_search' - for example *''whereis firefox''*

It will give you the directory in  which the file is located.

When you type ''whereis themes'' you should get something like this:

themes: /usr/share/themes

So the themes are inside /usr/share directory